# Is a compiled Qt 64 bits version needed to build an application for 64 bits machines?

Tags: c++, qt, build, migration, 64-bit

I recently finished migrating a project from Qt4 to Qt5, but [I am having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539820/disassembler-failed-cannot-access-memory-at-address-0x773dfff9-qt-debugging) because my platform is 64 bits, and I used a 32 bits Qt version, as well as a mingw 32 bits version to compile it. 
My question is, do I need to recompile Qt to make the program available for 64 bits platform? Or do I only need to change the compiler?

I have downloaded the [recommended package for 64 bits](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit) and I am doing things by trial and error, but I would like to know what do I exactly need to build this project properly.

Comment: 64 bit machines can run 32 bit applications just fine (not the other way around though)

Comment: @ratchetfreak could you answer that same thing on the question so I can mark it as right? the question was answered, it shouldnt be in a comment